# fdisk does not show boot flag

Tags: boot, fdisk

I normally use `fdisk -l` to look at partitions. I recently installed ubuntu 17.10 on a computer, and noticed that fdisk is not showing me the boot flag as it used to do. The output now looks for example like this

```
Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux filesystem
```

I've not been able to find any info on why the boot column is missing, or how to get it back. Any links/info on this?

`fdisk --version` gives me `fdisk from util-linux 2.30.1`. I have another computer with version 2.27 (ubuntu 16.04), and this does show me the boot flag.

Comment: Mine the same never paid attention until you mentioned this!

Comment: I think it is because of GPT - do you have line "`Disklabel type: gpt`" in the start of `fdisk -l` output?

Comment: @N0rbert yes I do!

Comment: I have GPT too, so I think it is normal for non-MBR partitioning (sda1 is EFI, no active flag).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of GPT.

On my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system `fdisk -l /dev/sda` shows the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: xxx GiB, yyyyyyyyyyyyy bytes, zzzzzzzzz sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
**Disklabel type: gpt**
Disk identifier: AAAAAAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    616447    614400   300M EFI System
...
```

But `sudo parted /dev/sda` shows almost the same:

```
(parted) p
Model: ATA ... (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: xxxGB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
**Partition Table: gpt**
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  316MB   315MB   fat32           EFI system partition          **boot**, esp
...
```

So `parted` correctly shows **boot** flag.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find this information programmatically (like I did) this command should do the trick for you.
`sudo parted -l 2>/dev/null | grep -B7 boot > temp.fil; grep Disk temp.fil; grep boot temp.fil; rm temp.fil`

This command produces output similar to this:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 120GB
Disk Flags: 
 1      1049kB  577MB  576MB  primary  ntfs         boot
```

For those who are unfamiliar with these commands, they work together as follows:

from `man parted`

```
-l, --list
              lists partition layout on all block devices
```

this is piped through `grep`

this was cleaned up by redirecting error output to `dev/null`  with `2>/dev/null` to eliminate the error message that my optical drive was generating in parted output.

From `man grep`

```
-B NUM, --before-context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines.  Places a line containing a group separator (--) between
              contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.
```

I chose to grab the first 7 lines and redirect into a temporary file `temp.fil` for ease of obtaining the output I required, You may find that you require a different number of lines before the match to get what you need. Each <kbd>;</kbd> indicates the start of a new command. `grep Disk temp.fil` returns the line in the temporary file that identifies the boot drive and `grep boot temp.fil` returns the line in the temporary file that identifies the boot partition. The `rm temp.fil` simply removes the temporary file previously created.

**NOTE:** This command string will overwrite any file called `temp.fil` in the current directory and then delete the result. If this is a problem for you change the name accordingly.